# Point isAbove, isUnder, isRight, isLeft methods

Tags: java

This is my point class;

```
public class Point
{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public boolean isAbove (Point other)
    {
        if (_y <= other._y)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean isUnder (Point other)
    {
        return isAbove(other);
    }

    public boolean isLeft (Point other)
    {
        if (_x >= other._x)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean isRight (Point other)
    {
        return isLeft(other);
    }
}
```

All the above methods not functional as expected and i cannot find what i am doing wrong. 
For example:

```
Point pp1 = new Point(1, 0);
Point pp2 = new Point(0, 0);
System.out.println("isAbove: " + pp1.isAbove(pp2));
System.out.println("isUnder: " + pp1.isUnder(pp2));
System.out.println("isLeft : " + pp1.isLeft(pp2));
System.out.println("isRight: " + pp1.isRight(pp2));
```

Return all false.

Comment: Take a look at your code. `isUnder(other)` will return the same result of `isAbove(other)`. Is this logic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
public boolean isAbove (Point other)
{
    return _y > other._y;       
}

public boolean isUnder (Point other)
{
    return other.isAbove(this);
}

public boolean isLeft (Point other)
{
    return _x < other._x;
}

public boolean isRight (Point other)
{
    return other.isLeft(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should negate `isRight` and `isUnder` and change <= to < and >= to >.

```
public class Point {
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
    }


    public boolean isUnder (Point other)
    {
        return _y < other._y;
    }

    public boolean isAbove (Point other) {
        return _y > other._y;
    }

    public boolean isLeft (Point other) {
        return _x < other._x;
    }

    public boolean isRight (Point other)
    {
       return _x > other._x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the isUnder become True (the 2 point has the same y value)

Comment: Both change <= to < and >= to >.

Comment: i didn't understand what you saying

Comment: my mistake. I've updated the answer. And result is : isAbove: true
isUnder: false
isLeft : true
isRight: false

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41953/discussion-between-user987339-and-user2214609)